# JSLint: Expected 'else { if' and instead saw 'else if

Tags: javascript, jslint

I am trying to validate a prompt in a JavaScript main function. Basically it asks for a number between 10 and 20. If the value does not fall within that range or is not a number, it should give an error message and ask again. If 0 is entered or the cancel button is pressed it should stop the routine completely.

I know this is pretty bad code, but it works for me perfectly.

The problem I am having is when I try to validate it in JSLint I get the following error:

```
Expected 'else { if' and instead saw 'else if'.
        } else if (amtEntered >= 10 && amtEntered <=20) {
```

If I uncomment the `return 0` statement, the  error is gone.

```
var amt;    
var inputError = false;

do {
    if (inputError) {
        alert ("You have entered an error. \n Please try again.");
    }
    amt = prompt("Enter amount between 10 and 20: ","");
    amt = Number(amt);
    if (isNaN(amt)) {
        inputError = true;
    } else if (amt === null || amt === 0) {
        // If amt is blank or cancel button pressed then exit loop and exit function.
        inputError = false;
        return 0;
    } else if (amt >= 10 && amt <=20) {
        inputError = false;
    } else {
        inputError = true;
    }
}
while (inputError);
```

Would appreciate any tips or recommendations on fixing this piece of code.

Comment: Your code is fine...it is JSLint that is super strict/picky...for a more forgiving but still-useful lint try: http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php

Comment: If we're going to nitpick why didn't you write amt === null as !amt  ?

Comment: Comment out the `return 0;` line and the message goes away. Looks like the `return` kicks in the `use_nested_if` option of _JSLint_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, two issues, I think, if you let the double `var` declaration and the `alert` and `prompt` slip by.  (I've "fixed" the `var`s by combining into one, added a jslint directive of `browser:true`, and added `window` before the `alert` and `prompt`, below.)

First, if you're literally using the code you've got above (and not checking it in the context of more code), you've got a `return` outside of a function, which is a little wacky.  So I've added `wrapMe()` to wrap it so that JSLint stops getting confused by the `return`, otherwise you get an `unexpected return` error even after the block disruption stuff mentioned below.

Second, it *is* the `return`, or, more specifically, [the "block.disrupt"](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/blob/master/jslint.js#L3433) (link is to JSLint's code as of today) that's upsetting JSLint.

Crockford wants you to immediately stop the block if you're returning.  No sense (in JSLint's mind) in `else` after a `return`.  That block can be pulled out of the `if` branching. That is, to JSLint, any code after a block containing a conditional disruption already *is* inherently an else equivalency, and to include the `else` is misleading -- again, in a JSLintian sense.

You get the point in any event.  You need to pull the `else` after the `block.disrupt` out, close out the `if` that includes the disruption, and start a new statement.

> Note that disrupt could also be a `break`, for instance.  So if you
>   had your original code and substituted a `break;` for `return 0;`,
>   you'd get the same admittedly somewhat misleading error.  (And then
>   you wouldn't have to wrap in a function.)

So the below is equivalent code to what you initially had in a format JSLint likes -- I believe.  I'm a little tired.

```
/*jslint sloppy:true, white:true, browser:true */

function wrapMe()   {
    var amt, inputError = false;

    do {
        if (inputError) {
            window.alert ("You have entered an error. \n Please try again.");
        }
        amt = window.prompt("Enter amount between 10 and 20: ","");
        amt = Number(amt);
        if (isNaN(amt)) {
            inputError = true;
        } else {
            if (amt === null || amt === 0) {
                // If amt is blank or cancel button pressed then exit loop and exit function.
                inputError = false;
                return 0;  // BLOCK DISRUPTION!!! (Not sure why that felt Scott Pilgrim-y)
            } 
            // If no disruption, continue.
            if (amt >= 10 && amt <=20) {
                inputError = false;
            } else {
                inputError = true;
            }
        }
    }
    while (inputError);
}
```

So instead of `else if`-ing after a block disruption, just use a new `if`.

Answer (score 5):

Well, you could *fix* it by changing your `if` statement to:

```
if (isNaN(amt)) {
    inputError = true;
} else {
    if (amt === null || amt === 0) {
        // If amt is blank or cancel button pressed then exit loop and exit function.
        inputError = false;
        return 0;
    } else {
        if (amt >= 10 && amt <=20) {
            inputError = false;
        } else {
            inputError = true;
        }
    }
}
```

But I think this is just JSLint being pedantic. What you have is actually valid syntax.

---

I believe the *reason* JSLint complains about things like this may be if you have code like:

```
if (condition)
    do_something();
```

and someone later changes it to:

```
if (condition)
    do_something();
    do_something_else();
```

Without the braces, that code isn't going to work as expected. Whether you consider that a good enough reason to pepper your code with more braces is mostly a matter of style.

This particular case is complicated by the fact that it only happens when the `return` statement is there, so the reasoning is more complex.

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/blob/master/jslint.js), it appears to load up the entire `if` block (the true branch) then check if the next token is `else`. If the `if` block has a disruptor (such as `return`), it complains about an unnecessary `else` (if the next token is `else`) or lack of braces (if the next token set is `else if`):

```
stmt('if', function () {
    var paren = next_token;
    one_space();
    advance('(');
    step_in('control');
    no_space();
    edge();
    this.arity = 'statement';
    this.first = expected_condition(expected_relation(expression(0)));
    no_space();
    step_out(')', paren);
    one_space();
    this.block = block('if');
    if (next_token.id === 'else') {
        if (this.block.disrupt) {
            next_token.warn(this.elif ? 'use_nested_if' : 'unnecessary_else');
        }
        one_space();
        advance('else');
        one_space();
        if (next_token.id === 'if') {
            next_token.elif = true;
            this.else = statement(true);
        } else {
            this.else = block('else');
        }
        if (this.else.disrupt && this.block.disrupt) {
            this.disrupt = true;
        }
    }
    return this;
});
```

The `unnecessary_else` is easy to figure out, it's to catch things like:

```
if (condition) {
    return 0;
} else {
    do_something();
}
```

In that case, it's better written as:

```
if (condition) {
    return 0;
}
do_something();
```

The `use_nested_if` is more interesting in that, if braces are a good idea, they should be used *all* the time, not just when the block has a `return` statement. I'm not sure *why* the author decided this was only a problem when a block returned.

If it really bothered you, you could no doubt modify the code to remove that check, not something I'd do lightly. Perhaps it may be better to ask the author to add the `tolerate_non_nested_if` option to the software. Or, you could just ignore the warnings if you know it's okay.

---

And, on further reflection, it may be that the *same* reasoning is being used for both warnings - if you have an `if` block that returns, any code after that should not be in the equivalent `else` block, it should be stand-alone (but in the context of any outer `if/else` blocks of course).

By that I mean you could probably use:

```
if (isNaN(amt)) {
    inputError = true;
} else {
    if (amt === null || amt === 0) {
        // If amt is blank or cancel button pressed then exit loop and exit function.
        inputError = false;
        return 0;
    } // no else needed here.
    if (amt >= 10 && amt <=20) {
        inputError = false;
    } else {
        inputError = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good explanation of **why** jsLint is complaining

Comment: This explanation talks about braceless statements, but OPs code doesn't use braceless statements.

Comment: @Paul, `... else if (x) {y}` _has_ a braceless statement, it's the `if (x) {y}` bit. That's why it wants `... else { if (x) {y} }` instead.

Comment: You're welcome for [reflecting further](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25800269/1028230).  ;)  No probably about it. The code from my answer is JSLint compliant.

Comment: I'll give you one for that, @ruffin, I didn't actually _get_ it from your answer, I was too busy struggling over on JSLint and GitHub to try figure out what the heck the author was thinking :-) But you've explained that aspect better than I have, so +1.

Comment: Yeah, it's worth having a local, properly whitespaced copy of `jslint.js` to step through a debugger sometimes, as that merged & minimized copy he's got online is a real pain. Sometimes Crockford's ideals are best investigated through his code, and I'm happy it's all JavaScript (so anyone using JSLint can debug JSLint, within reason), but wow, you're absolutely right, tough to suss sometimes. ;^)  And though I like this rule, the error reported is awfully misleading.

Answer (score 1):

*JSLint* is being picky about your code, which is valid, but (in my opinion) has a very odd structure. Consider a design like this instead

```
var amt,
    fail = true;
// would use `while (amt = prompt("Enter amount between 10 and 20: ", ""))` personally
amt = prompt("Enter amount between 10 and 20: ", "");
while (amt) {
    amt = +amt; // to Number
    if (10 <= amt && amt <= 20) {
        fail = false;
        break;
    }
    alert("You have entered an error. \n Please try again.");
    amt = prompt("Enter amount between 10 and 20: ", "");
}
if (fail) {
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could have something to do with the `return 0;`; an `else` isn’t needed when that condition has been reached. Of course, since the `return` is in an `else if`, the fix is less straightforward, and the suggested fix doesn’t really make much sense.

Luckily, you can simplify!

```
var amt;
var inputError = false;

while (true) {
    if (inputError) {
        alert ("You have entered an error. \n Please try again.");
    }

    inputError = true;

    amt = prompt("Enter amount between 10 and 20: ");

    if (!amt) {
        return;
    }

    amt = Number(amt);

    if (isNaN(amt)) {
        continue;
    }

    if (amt >= 10 && amt <= 20) {
        break;
    }
}
```

… assuming you have enough checks to warrant not just doing this:

```
if (!amt) {
    return;
}

amt = +amt;
inputError = !(amt >= 10 && amt <= 20); // NaN will always compare as false here
```

Comment: No, it's the picky-ness of JSLint because I used JSLint in the past... e.g., if you don't indent your lines of code to the programmer's liking (whoever wrote it), you will get deluged by warnings

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob: Why didn’t it complain at the first `else if`, then?

Comment: Good point...I can't refute it....but try JSLint (if you haven't already) and see how picky it is about any JS code you write (at least, that's how I felt about it)

Comment: minitech, interesting on the non-complaint for the first `else if` bit. According to the source, it only complains about `if (x) {y} else if ...` if the `y` has a disruptor (such as `return`). Not sure why author thought that was a needed restriction, it seems to me braces would be good _all_ the time.

Comment: @paxdiablo: Why would braces be good all the time? `else if` is a terribly common idiom. Anyways, it makes sense as a restriction; the fix just isn’t as easy as what it suggests, because it’s probably not taking into account that the `if` containing a flow control statement is itself part of an `else if`…

Comment: `else if` _is_ common, it's also prone to the same errors as `else x=7` if you want to do _two_ things at some point in the else block: `else { if (x) {y}; a = b; }` is different to `else if (x) {y}; a = b;`. It's fine if the complete `if` statement will be the only thing in the `else` block but code evolves. Note I'm didn't intend to say you _should_ have braces, I believe the right time to add them is when you add a second statement to the `else` block. I'm just stating why some might find it desirable.

Comment: @paxdiablo: It’s not prone to those errors, though, if you use it with braces after the `if`. Using them around both the `else` and the `if` doesn’t really help with that.

Comment: Err, yes, I believe it is. Contrast the two examples I gave in the previous comment, they don't have the same effect. Note that neither of them is `else { if (x) { y; a = b; } }`. I was talking about the case where you had two _distinct_ statements in the `else`: an `if (x) {y}` and a totally unrelated assignment (that has nothing to do with the condition `x`).

Comment: @paxdiablo: Sure, but that’s not an easy mistake to make. If you have https://gist.github.com/anonymous/07fd1ac680e90cbee456, you’re not going to accidentally add an indented line beneath the last brace and mistakenly believe it’s still part of the block…